.NET ImageSharp Crop and Resize throws error
I'm converting some older code to .NET 8 and using the ImageSharp (3.1.4) library. It is processing an uploaded image, centers it,crops it, resizes it and saves the file.
Here is my code:
public void ResizeCropAndSaveImage(IFormFile file, int cropWidth, int cropHeight, string filePath, string fileName)
{
    using (Image image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        // get the shorter side & scale percentages
        var ratio = Math.Min((float)image.Width / cropWidth, (float)image.Height / cropHeight);
        var scaleH = Convert.ToInt32(cropHeight * ratio);
        var scaleW = Convert.ToInt32(cropWidth * ratio);

        // set crop from center coordinates
        var posX = (image.Width - scaleW) / 2;
        var posY = (image.Height - scaleH) / 2;

        var resizedImage = image.Clone(i => i.Resize(cropWidth, cropHeight).Crop(new Rectangle(posX, posY, scaleW, scaleH)));

        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        resizedImage.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), new JpegEncoder());
    }
}

But it's throwing the following error:

System.ArgumentException: Crop rectangle should be smaller than the source bounds. (Parameter 'cropRectangle')

The error seems self explanatory, but the new Rectangle() is smaller than the source images so I'm not sure what's happening?

Please add a note as to which version of ImageSharp your code is using

ImageSharp version 3.1.4

What do you mean by "centers it"? It's an image by itself, right? There's nothing to center it into... - or do you mean you're centering the crop-rect?

You are resizing to cropWidth x cropHeight then cropping to those numbers TIMES ratio.  Unless ratio is less than 1, that's going to fail.

@Dai, yes I'm trying to center the crop rectangle.

I need to confirm, but unless there's a reason to do things in the order you're attempting... it's probably better to crop, then resize. I suspect the math you're applying is creating a crop area that's offset (so, like the error says, outside the bounds of the image)

In a word, your code crops image first, which leads to scaleW + posX larger than cropWidth or the height, of same effect and extends beyond borders of original image. So as @Abolfazl Moslemian says you can first crop then resize separately. SixLabor document provides the new method. https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/processing.html

The issue is happening because you're resizing the image before cropping, which can lead to invalid crop dimensions. You should crop the image first, then resize it. Here's how you can fix it:

Crop the image to the right size from the center
Resize the cropped image
Save the resized image

using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using System;
using System.IO;

public void ResizeCropAndSaveImage(IFormFile file, int cropWidth, int cropHeight, string filePath, string fileName)
{
    using (Image image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
    {
        //get the shorter side & scale percentages
        var ratio = Math.Min((float)image.Width / cropWidth, (float)image.Height / cropHeight);
        var scaledH = (int)(cropHeight * ratio);
        var scaledW= (int)(cropWidth * ratio);

        // Set crop from center coordinates
        var posX = (image.Width - scaledWidth) / 2;
        var posY = (image.Height - scaledHeight) / 2;

        // Crop the image first
        image.Mutate(i => i.Crop(new Rectangle(posX, posY, scaledWidth, scaledHeight)));

        // Resize the cropped image
        image.Mutate(i => i.Resize(cropWidth, cropHeight));

        Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
        image.Save(Path.Combine(filePath, fileName), new JpegEncoder());
    }
}


